# Using Jupyter notebook - which is best for this tkinter algrithm? quit(), exit(), sys.exit(), or os.exit()?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, exit

I am using the Jupyter notebook to write a tkinter algorithm with a lot of "if" statements.

I would like some of these "if" statements to stop running the program (but not stop the tkinter window from running) at certain points without returning to the main flow of the code.  I wrote a small sample app (below) to illustrate what I mean.

I have tried using quit(), exit(), sys.exit(), and os.exit(). Both quit() and exit() seem to work okay,They say "Hi" and not "bye", as expected.  But I still get some unwanted readout when I close the tkinter window - which I think may be more Jupyters fault than python or tkinter.  It usually says, "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

The sample script contains each of the commands above, and it uses a comment "#" to toggle the line on and off.  The unwanted readout and messages for each case are also commented beside the code in the script.

My concern is whether the unwanted readout could be problematic or even a security threat if I code any further, since some of these if statements will be used in a password protected area.  Would I be correct in assuming, if the unwanted messages came from Jupyter, the messages will be benign and transparent once I compile the code to an exe?

My code is below:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk

import sys
import os

def routine ():
    
    x = 0

    if x < 1:

        print("Hi")

    # quit()  # Prints Hi and not bye; 
              # when destroyed, it says Kernel Restarting
              # The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
            
    # exit()  # On an apparent level - it seems to do all the same things as quit.
    
    # sys.exit()    # Prints Hi
                    # and then...
                    # An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
                    # SystemExit
                    # Then the entire systems, including the tkinter window, 
                    # locks up and spin doing nothing.
                    # The close button wont even work.

    # os._exit()  # Exception in Tkinter callback
                # Traceback (most recent call last):
                # File "C:\Users\rrr\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
                # return self.func(*args)
                # File "<ipython-input-3-c9d340ae6a31>", line 31, in routine
                # os._exit()
                # TypeError: _exit() missing required argument 'status' (pos 1)

    if x > 1:

        print("bye...")


root = Tk()  
root.geometry("300x200+200+200")

btn1 = Button(root, text ="Run A Routine", command = routine)
btn1.pack(pady = 20, anchor='center')

btn1 = Button(root, text ="Close Window", command = root.destroy)
btn1.pack(pady = 20, anchor='center')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you problem is from jupyter. Jupyter runs all your notebook trough a kernel. When you use exit() you close the kernel and jupyter complains. This brings the question why are you using jupyter to code if you want to compile it into an exe? Also, what do you mean by `code any further`? There is no code running after killing the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering what you mean by "stop running the program"? Do you mean exit the function/subroutine that you have written? Because if that is the case, you should simply use `return` to exit the defined routine.

If you want to do something more complex, you may need to remove your `.mainloop()` call for updating tkinter, and instead use something like the below:

```
RUN_FLAG = True
while RUN_FLAG:
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

This would allow you to update the global variable `RUN_FLAG` in your subroutine and use that to move beyond your tkinter and then finish your script.

Also, side note; Running tkinter in Jupyter is a bit odd, in my opinion. If your solution gets much more extensive, you'd probably get better performance from a standard python script. I recommend "PyCharm" by JetBrains as an IDE.

Comment: btw, you both are right about using Jupyter as an odd place for writing tkinter code.  One night I was programming python in Jupyter and discovered I could run tkinter apps by pasting the code into Jupyter.  I have done it ever since.  I know its quirky, but I can almost hand code a GUI using it now.    I will give PyCharm a look, although I want to make sure its free and all.

Answer (score 0):

Angus B: I liked your thought on using return, which I didnt know I could do - because I am still too new at programming.  But it seems to work like I wanted it.  The code below demonstrates what I mean.

If you ran it as it is, then it would stop at the return command in line 7, and it would print "Hi A" to the command line.

But if you commented out Line 7, then it would print

"Hi A"
"Hi B"

I dont quite understand the difference between using return versus using exit or quit, but return seems to do more of what I want.  I will continue to study it.  Thank you for your response. :)

For the record, my question may not have been cutting edge research, but it is a bit different and it has been answered.  We can continue to discuss it, if you like.

```
import tkinter

def routine (x):
    
    if x == "A":
        print("Hi A1")
        return
        
    if x == "B":
        print("Hi B")
    
    if x == "A":
        print("Hi A2")        
            
root = Tk()  
root.geometry("300x200+200+200")

btn1 = Button(root, text ="Run A Routine", command = lambda: routine("A"))
btn1.pack(pady = 20, anchor='center')

btn1 = Button(root, text ="Close Window", command = root.destroy)
btn1.pack(pady = 20, anchor='center')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Regarding the difference between the different commands:

- ```exit()``` and ```quit()``` are synonyms, and they close all python processes; they are a full exit from the process.

- ```return``` causes you to return from the current function that you are in, and you can give it arguments that cause it to return a value to the caller.